# How can I pipe sound into a custom sound device from Node.js

Tags: node.js, audio

I'm trying to play the audio output from Google's STT API on a custom audio device (a VB-Cable).

How can I select the audio device from Node.js? I've tried using NaudioDon, but I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Channel count exceeds maximum number of channels for device
```

Is there a specific library someone's used to do something like this in the past?